# How to start Wolf's AMD miner on boot with Ubuntu?

Tags: mining-software, linux

How can I set Wolf's AMD miner (version 0.4) to start on boot with Ubuntu 16.04?

I already have the miner configured to run properly on command in my Downloads folder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/runminer.service`

In there, paste this (everything between the lines):

---

[Unit]
Description=Monero GPU miner
After=network.target

[Service]
User=**YOUR_USER_NAME_HERE**
Group=**YOUR_USER_NAME_HERE**
WorkingDirectory=~

Type=simple
ExecStart=**PUT_LAUNCH_COMMAND_HERE_USING_FULL_PATHS**

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

---

After that, do

`sudo systemctl enable runminer.service`

Then, to launch right now.

`sudo service runminer start`

Or just reboot it. To see if its running, run

`sudo service runminer status`

to see the full logs, try

`sudo journalctl -u runminer.service`

(caveat - I think that should all work. Haven't tried it yet)

Comment: Somewhere in there you're going to need to set the DISPLAY environment variable. The AMD drivers require an active X server. Also I'm not sure this will work past an actual login. I.e., the X server that the display manager/login window uses may not allow the miner to share the server with the logged-in user.

Answer (score 1):

I found it easier to use the app [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/).

sudo apt-get install screen

Then, do as Ginger Ale advised..

> sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/runminer.service

[Unit]
Description=Start Up My Miner
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=YOUR_USER_NAME
ExecStart=/usr/bin/screen -d -m -S miner PATH_TO_MINER
ExecStop=/usr/bin/killall -w -s 2 miner
WorkingDirectory=PATH_TO_HOME_DIRECTORY

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

If you're interested, check out [how to autostart a screen with systemd](http://www.linuxveda.com/2014/04/28/autostart-process-gnu-screen-systemd/) and this helpful stack question on how to write startup scripts.